# Which yellow answer completes the sequence?

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction, pattern

Which yellow circle is next in the sequence and why?[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A possible answer would be

> A

because

> All images in the sequence can be drawn using 4 lines.

Comment: so can C and E if you stop halfway then carry on.

Comment: To me, when I look at it, A is made of 5 lines. Three vertical (two longest on the right, and then one small one at the beginning of the structure). Then 2 horizontal. I'm probably missing something though?